# What is the effect on primary keys when moving a CLUSTERED index to a new filegroup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filegroups

I'm moving a `CLUSTERED` index from one filegroup to another, using the `with drop_existing=on` functionality.

Do I need to be concerned about primary keys?  In other words, is there some special handling I need to do to retain the existing primary/unique key?

I have tables on the primary filegroup that I need to move to a new filegroup. There are some tables with and some without indexes, some with and some without clustered indexes, and amongst those, some with and some without Primary Keys.

I'm wondering if there is any special handling I should consider for the tables with Primary Keys during the `CREATE INDEX` statements?

Does this even matter in this scenario?

Comment: @marc_s: it's not just DBAs in the "backup+restore monkey" sense. There are BI, NoSQL and advanced SQL questions. And not just SQL Server. Come and see http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap

Comment: ^ yes, that's an advert. Nothing personal :-)

Comment: Is there anything specific you're worried might happen, or are you just asking for any general precautions to take for this operation?

Comment: @Nick Chammas:  Mostly general precaution, but I was thinking about how if a table doesn't have an existing clustered index, and then you add a primary key, it creates a clustered index, and I'm concerned that using the create index statement, it's dropping the PK because of this.  Then of course, when it recreates it on the new filegroup, it does it as a regular index or something, and possibly killing any relational dependancies.

Comment: Fair enough.  Show us the script you intend to use for the move, along with the DDL for the table.

Answer (score 2):

No.

From an "on disk" organisation perspective the fact it is a constraint doesn't matter. That is, the physical and logical table layouts are separate

And PK when not clustered is just a unique non-clustered index with some rules

Comment: Ok, so just to be clear, performing this action, isn't going to say drop any primary keys or anything like this, correct?

It's just going to move the actual data to the new filegroup and not reseting anything (as far as data I mean)?

And thanks!

Comment: @user1088571: Correct. You are simply changing physical disk location: no other logical or DDL changes will happen